# listview with hidden alternate row

Tags: android, listview

for you is posttible to create a layout for a listview with 2 little row into a row with the second one hidden and if you click the first one the second one appear?

in javascript i use this

```
`<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function mostra(){
document.getElementById('testo').style.display='';
}
function nascondi(){
document.getElementById('testo').style.display='none';}
//-->
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function mostra(){
document.getElementById('testo').style.display='';
}
function nascondi(){
document.getElementById('testo').style.display='none';}
//-->
</script>`
```

but I don't know how to make in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking about listview with expandable option.you might want to
Take a look at android Expandable Listview 
https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
or you can take a look at Expandable Recylerview 
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview
hope this helps.